# How to remove duplicate data in KeyValuePairs SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, key-value

I have a KeyValuePairs which gets duplicates, I can't figure out how to remove them. The KeyValuePairs is created like this:

```
var pairs:KeyValuePairs<String, Color> = [:]
```

Example (What I have and what I want):

```
pairs_withDuplicate = 
[
"Cat" : Color.red,
"Dog" : Color.blue, 
"Bird" : Color.yellow, 
"Cat" : Color.red
] 

-->

pairs_withoutDuplicate = 
[
"Cat" : Color.red, 
"Dog" : Color.blue, 
"Bird" : Color.yellow
]
```

For a given string, example "Cat" will always be given the same color. So The whole pair will be a duplicate. Not that only the string is duplicate with different colors. So if a duplicate within the keys/strings is found I want the pair to be removed. Thankful for any tips.

Kind regards, Pontus

Comment: Can you show some example input and outputs?

Comment: Have you thought about using an Ordered Dictionary?https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md

Comment: @Andrew Yes, have to use KeyValuePairs as I'm using it for an Swift Charts implementation which requires it.

Comment: @Sweeper added example, hope this was what you meant otherwise tell me :)

Comment: Removing duplicates would best be done at insertion, but that would require checking each entry as KeyValuePairs doesn’t require the key to be hashable so you aren’t getting the benefit of the dictionary’s automatic overwriting upon insertion. Perhaps storing the data in an ordered dictionary and converting it to KeyValuePairs for use with the chart.

Comment: I suggest, you are better off using an array of pairs/tuples, like this:
                 `var uniqPairs: [(String,Color)] = pairs_withDuplicate.map{ ($0.key , $0.value) }`
                 Use this in your Charts, it is more flexible than `KeyValuePairs`.